# Hiding div using jQuery and select onchange persistently

Tags: jquery, html, css, hide, show

I'm having trouble with hiding a div using select and onchange function. The function written in jQuery is working, it is showing and hiding div when I change select option values but when I return to the page later it shows div even though option in select is set to a value that should hide div.

I need to check the value of select option upon loading page and set display of the div according to that value, how do I do that?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<select name="cancelation" class="dropdown">
   <option value="refundable">Refundable</option>
   <option value="non-refundable">Non-Refundable</option>
</select>

<div class="row cancelationDaysRow">
    <span class="no-margin-left">Up to</span>
        <div class="input-holder"><input name="cancelationDays" id="cancelation" 
             title="<?php echo $this->__('Cancelation days') ?>" 
             placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('30') ?>" value="30" 
             class="input-text input-text_inner" type="text" 
             onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')" maxlength="3"/>
        </div>
    <span>days before the starting date of this tour</span>
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery function:

```
 l$('#addTourForm select[name="cancelation"]').on('change', function(){
        $value = l$(this).val();
        //console.log($value);
        if($value == 'refundable'){
            l$('.cancelationDaysRow').css('display', 'inline-block');
        }else{
            l$('.cancelationDaysRow').css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
```

**EDIT** In the console, when I'm changing values of select I'm getting an error: *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .ListPicker._handleMouseUp @ about:blank:502*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just trigger an initial change event on the select.

e.g. using `.change()` or `.trigger("change")`:

```
l$('#addTourForm select[name="cancelation"]').on('change', function(){
    $value = l$(this).val();
    //console.log($value);
    if($value == 'refundable'){
        l$('.cancelationDaysRow').css('display', 'inline-block');
    }else{
        l$('.cancelationDaysRow').css('display', 'none');
    }
}).change();
```

Here is a simple mockup with the "Non-refundable" selected at the start:

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/cm2yzch0/

### Notes:

- To avoid a visual glitch on page load, you would typically set the div to be initially hidden, as it is better to show it on DOM ready, if needed, than to hide it after being visible for a split second during page load.
- You code does not show where the jQuery code is run, but typically it would be inside a DOM ready handler. The shortcut version is `jQuery(function(){Your code here});`

e.g.

```
l$(function(){
    l$('#addTourForm select[name="cancelation"]').on('change', function(){
        $value = l$(this).val();
        //console.log($value);
        if($value == 'refundable'){
            l$('.cancelationDaysRow').css('display', 'inline-block');
        }else{
            l$('.cancelationDaysRow').css('display', 'none');
        }
    }).change();
});
```

- You can also reduce your code to one line using `toggle` with a boolean value:

e.g.

```
$('#addTourForm select[name="cancelation"]').on('change', function () {
    $('.cancelationDaysRow').toggle($(this).val() == 'refundable');
}).trigger('change');
```

Comment: @dmikic: So long as the above code is run in a DOM ready handler it will fire the same logic as if you selected that item.You may have another issue present.

Comment: In your mockup you've added "selected" attribute in select option "Non-refundable" so it is working, but without it, div is still seen. And if I keep "selected" attribute, it will only inverse the problem.

Comment: Your code says "if the value is `refundable`, show the div". *What exactly did you expect to happen?* :) I set that value to show what happens if the page is posted with that option selected... which is what you would expect/want.

Comment: It says "if the value is `refundable` show the div, if it's 'non-refundable` do not show the div." Or at least is supposed to say that :)

Comment: That was a typo in my comment... that is what the example does: "If refundable is selected, the div is shown, any other value it will not be shown"... As this is using your exact code, what exactly do you thing is wrong with the example? :)

Comment: Please note: You have no "blank" selection in your `select`, so the first element is selected if nothing else is selected.

Comment: Well it's not working, somehow it keeps showing the div upon returning to the page, even though "Non-refundable" is selected. The only thing I managed to do so far is to inverse the problem. Your logic is right and it should work, but somehow it just doesn't :)

Comment: That indicates there is something else wrong on the page. Any javascript error will stop the code running. Please show your entire page with all code. Also: Are you using a DOM ready wrapper on your jQuery?

Comment: If there was an error on the page, it wouldn't change display at all, would it? Well, my entire page has 2000 lines of code, so I suppose that's out of question :)

Comment: Open the F12 console in Chrome etc and see if it is breaking somewhere. Also (again): is your jQuery in a DOM ready handler? You could put the entire page output into a jSFiddle and post the link if necessary.

Comment: Well the problem with JSFiddle is that I have external js file with jQuery code in it, and panel.html file and when I copy it in fiddle it doesn't work at all. You helped me a lot and I will try to come up to solution for my problem with your logic. The problem is I'm not the one who wrote all this code, I'm just the guy wos is fixing bugs, 'cause the other guy who wrote it is not working on this project anymore and left it unfinished. Thank you very much for your help, I will definitely mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: I'm actually getting an error in console when I'm changing values of select. Console is showing: _Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .ListPicker._handleMouseUp @ about:blank:502_
Sorry, I'm a beginner, didn't notice this error before.

Comment: Also, when I'm loading page it shows me: [http://screencast.com/t/m1QIfFyd0r7](http://screencast.com/t/m1QIfFyd0r7)
It didn't show me this message with my first solution

Answer (score 0):

You should have your div hidden by using inline css "style='display:none'" by default

```
<div class="row cancelationDaysRow" style="display:none">
   <span class="no-margin-left">Up to</span>
    <div class="input-holder"><input name="cancelationDays" id="cancelation" 
         title="<?php echo $this->__('Cancelation days') ?>" 
         placeholder="<?php echo $this->__('30') ?>" value="30" 
         class="input-text input-text_inner" type="text" 
         onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')" maxlength="3"/>
    </div>
   <span>days before the starting date of this tour</span> </div>
```

Hope this help!

Comment: That will not work if the initial selection means it is visible.

Comment: or you can '<div class="row cancelationDaysRow" style="<?php ($initialValueIsTrue) ? "" : "display:none" >">'. Where $initialValueIsTrue is the initial value where it makes the div visible. Will that work?

Comment: It will, but it overcomplicates the server code, when a simple `change` trigger is all that is normally needed in these cases.

Comment: I think the above solution is the right solution for the change event will not work if the page is being loaded. Since it needs to have a default value in order for the div to be shown.

Comment: jQuery code is typically fired after the DOM is ready. Firing the select at that time will hide or show the div as required. I added a JSFiddle mockup to show the simplest solution does work.